# uncoupling pertubated 2-D harmonic oszillator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, harmonic-oscillator, linear-algebra

I want to exactly solve a two dimensional harmonic oscillator with

$$ \mathcal{H} = \dfrac{p_x^2}{2m} + \dfrac{p_y^2}{2m} + \dfrac{m\omega^2}{2}(x^2+y^2+2K xy)$$

I understand that I have to find a substitution to reduce the problem to the case of two uncoupled harmonic oscillators,but I am struggling to find a substitution in a straight forward way.

I think a more general formulation of the problem is (assuming a linear transformation) to find an invertible matrix $A$ with $\bar{x}=Ax$ such that given a quadratic form

$$q=x^TMx = (A^{-1}\bar{x})^TMA^{-1}\bar{x}=\bar{x}^T(A^{-1})^TMA^{-1}\bar{x}$$

then

$$(A^{-1})^TMA^{-1}$$ 
is diagonal.

(In my case $M = \begin{pmatrix}1 & K \\ K & 1 \end{pmatrix}$)

This is a similar condition to the case when diagonalizing a regular matrix, but how do I find $A$ in this case?

EDIT: I guess using $x^2+y^2+2Kxy = (x+Ky)^2 - K^2y^2 +y^2 = (x+Ky)^2 +(1-K^2)y^2$ hence $A = \begin{pmatrix}1 & K \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$ does the job, but how is this generalizable?

Answer (score 0):

The way you want to approach this, is by defining new operators $\tilde{x}$, $\tilde{y}$ and $\tilde{p}_{x}$ and $\tilde{p}_{y}$.

The transformation is pretty simple. From what I recall something along the lines of
$$
\tilde{x}, \tilde{y} = (2)^{-1/2}(x \pm y)
$$
and similar for the new $\tilde{p}$'s.

You want to pick these new operators such that your earlier $H$ in terms of $x$
, $y$, $p_{x}$ and $p_{y}$ is exactly equal to:
$$
H = \frac{1}{2m}(\tilde{p}_{x}^{2} + \tilde{p}_{y}^{2}) + \frac{m \tilde{\omega}^{2}}{2}(\tilde{x}^{2} +\tilde{y}^{2})
$$
You'll notice that you will now have a new $\tilde{\omega}$, which is going to be some function of $K$ and $\omega$.

Once you're able to do this, you can write down the energies simply as $E_{n,m} = \hbar \tilde{\omega} (n +m +1)$, and similarly for the eigenfunctions.